# How to correct transfer 2D tensor to custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to transfer a 2D tensor(GlobalAveragePooling2D output) to custom layer

```
input_shape = (1, 4, 5, 10)
x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)
y = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
print(y.shape)
print(y)

#output
(1, 10)
tf.Tensor(
[[ 2.9310981e-02  1.9502535e-01  6.6027664e-02  2.8112438e-01  -5.6703627e-02 
  -1.7071962e-04 -2.3066494e-01  3.4020171e-01  -6.7941666e-02 -6.0300839e-01]],
  shape=(1, 10), dtype=float32)
```

Transfer a tensor to MaxpoolingLayer , get error message.

Why init get two positional argument

```
class MaxpoolingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MaxpoolingLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        #do something at input_tensor
        return input_tensor
z = MaxpoolingLayer(y)

#error message
TypeError
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
  File "C:\layertest.py", line 21, in <module>
    z = MaxpoolingLayer(y)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I tried to let init take 2 positional argument, but when I dont know how to use these 2 variables in custom layer

Comment: `self` is passed implicitly, while you also pass some variable `y`. What is `y` and why do you pass it in `MaxpoolingLayer(y)`?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I want to do something at GlobalAveragePooling2D output,  so I pass the output(y) to MaxpoolingLayer

Comment: typos, It should be like `MaxpoolingLayer()(y)` for being a class.

Comment: it works, thank you